# Teradata 15: Error 2666 einvalid date) - How to find the broken value?

Tags: sql, teradata

I am trying to use the following condition in `WHERE` clause:

```
WHERE birth_dt IS NOT NULL
AND issue_dt IS NOT NULL
AND(

    (
       age>20
       AND (birth_dt + INTERVAL '20' YEAR) > issue_dt
    )
    OR
    (
       age > 45
       AND (birth_dt + INTERVAL '45' YEAR) > issue_dt
    ))
```

Recieving following error:

```
SELECT Failed. 2666:  Invalid date supplied for cldata.birth_dt.
```

If i comment the second part of condition (`OR age > 45... etc`), it works normally. 
So i've concluded, that there is some row on that interval, with broken value of `birth_dt`. 
I would like to exclude or ignore that row, but don't know how. So how to do that?
Or maybe there is some other solution? 
Thx

Comment: What is the data type of `birth_dt`?

Answer (score 0):

Solution is found - the second clause was rewritten like this:

```
 (
       age > 45
       AND (birth_dt + INTERVAL '44' YEAR + INTERVAL '365' DAY) > issue_dt
    )
```

:)
Seems like bug..

Answer (score 0):

When someone is born on Feb 29th adding 45 years will result in an invalid date (due to stupid rules in Standard SQL), e.g.

```
date '1972-02-29' + interval '45' year = '2017-02-29' = invalid date
```

Never add/subtract INTERVAL MONTH/YEAR, always use ADD_MONTHS instead

```
add_months(date '1972-02-29', 45*12) = '2017-02-28'
```